# Writing a migration for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a model in which i'l be using same resource at two locations:

```
class AttachmentFileComment < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :action_type

belongs_to :attachments, :conditions=>['attachments.attachable_type=?', 'project']
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :approval_level
belongs_to :comments
belongs_to :attachments, :as=> :file_id, :conditions=>['attachments.attachable_type=?', 'attachment']

end
```

For above how can i write a migration

Comment: Try to read this help - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: belongs_to associations need to be singular. ie `belongs_to :user`, and you can't have two associations with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggesion. Then what should i do These two fileds are what i want in the new table.